# "Http failure response for http://localhost:49540/api/create/: 404 Not Found" Angular 11 POST request

Tags: c#, angular

I am currently developing a client app using Angular 11, that consumes .Net 5 API. The API get request is working as expected but when I send a POST request it fails with the error saying

> POST http://localhost:49540/api/create/ 404 (Not Found) 
> Http failure response for http://localhost:49540/api/create/: 404 Not Found

I have tried removing the trailing slash at the end but it didn't help.

**Here my API action method**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBook(CreateBook model)
    {
        var book = mapper.Map<Book>(model);

        // Replace value with userManager.GetUserId(User); 
        try
        {
            book.CreatedByUserId = Fakes.Faker.FakeUserId();
            book.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            book.BookStatus = BookStatus.Available;
            book.BookId = new Guid();

            return Ok(await bookService.AddAsync(book));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new ResponseMessage
            {
                Succeeded = false,
                Errors = new List<string>() { ex.Message }
            });
        }
    }
 }
```

**Client Code**

```
addBook(book: CreateBook): Observable<CreateBook> {
 return this.httpClient.post<CreateBook>(baseURL + 'create', book, {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   })
 }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
   if (errorResponse instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error("Client side error: ", errorResponse);
   } else {
      console.error("Server side Error: " + errorResponse.message);
   }
  return throwError("Message");
}
```

I have configured CORS to allow any header, method and origin.
What is the problem? Is it with my code or there is something Missed? I am confused because get request works correctly, also the post request is working in Swagger.

Comment: Try removing the `/api/` from the url. Do you have a route attribute on the controller?

Comment: yes it is, check the code

Comment: I see a Route attribute on your _action_, I'm asking if there is one on the _controller_ (the class). Which url gives you a 200?

Comment: Ok, yes `[Route("api/[controller])]`  wait let me edit the question

Comment: So then you're missing the name of the controller in the url.

Comment: yep. it should be api/books/create

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks very much... I wasted a whole day with just this...please add it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current url fails because you're missing a fragment in the path. To understand why, let's look at your *controller's* `[Route]` attribute.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

This means the path segment of the url must start with `/api/Books`, because your controller is named "Books" (this works by taking the class name and removing the word "Controller" from the end if it exists).

This is then appended with the *action's* `[Route]` attribute.

```
[Route("create")]
```

So the full expected url path is `/api/Books/create`. "Books" can also be lowercase if you want, the code will understand it either way.

For further reading, see [Routing in ASP.NET Core - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your  action route attribute

```
[HttpPost]
 [Route("~/api/create")]
 [Route("~/api/books/create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBook(CreateBook model)
```